# Is it possible to sort RLMResults by the count of an RLMArray property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I'd like to sort the objects contained by an `RLMResults` instance by the `count` of an `RLMArray` property of those objects.

Person.h:

```
@interface Person : RLMObject

@property RLMArray *children;

@end
```

SomeClass.m:

```
...
RLMResults *people = [Person allObjects];
RLMResults *sorted = [people sortedResultsUsingProperty:@"children.count" ascending:YES];
...
```

Using `- sortedResultsUsingProperty:` as done above doesn't work, however, giving an error: `Cannot sort on 'people.count': sorting on key paths is not supported.`

What's the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: I think you may just have slightly wrong syntax, what if you try children.@count instead?

Comment: I tried that too, but in both cases you get the same error: `Cannot sort on 'people.@count': sorting on key paths is not supported.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far you can only sort by actual properties. We want to add support for what you want to achieve here, see [issue #1277](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1277) for reference. For now you'd need to introduce a property `childrenCount`, which you would maintain manually and keep in sync with `children`. Alternatively, you can extract your results into a `NSArray` and sort that <del>in a similar manner</del> via Foundation's API.

The latter proposal could be implemented like shown here:

```
RLMResults *people = [Person allObjects];
NSArray *peopleObjects = [people valueForKey:@"self"];
NSArray *sortedPeople [peopleObjects sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(Person *a, Person *b) {
    return a.children.count < b.children.count
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, if I extract the results into an `NSArray`, I still wouldn't be able to sort `NSSortDescriptor` with a key of `@"children.count"` since I get the error `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key count.` Do you have any recommendations for sorting another way?

Comment: You have to use `@count`.

Comment: But it turns out that a further technical limitations will prevent you from using `NSSortDescriptor`: Our collection types are indeed not yet compliant to KVC collection operators. This is tracked by [issue #2937](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2937). So you'd need to sort e.g. by using a block-based API as offered by [`- [NSArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingComparator:).

Comment: @marius Can you please tell me how to convert NSArray into RLResults?

Comment: @user3182143: `NSArray` is a Foundation-based collection which can hold arbitrary individual objects.`RLMResults` is a read-only data structure to represent the results of a query without pulling all objects of one class into memory. You cannot instantiate an object of this class yourself. So there is no way to convert.